# Bad camera image with ZXing

Tags: google-glass, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to use the ZXing library on Google Glass.

But, when I start the activity with this lines:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE","QR_CODE_MODE"); // Para códigos QR
intent.putExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Cuadra el QR para escanearlo");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The camera loads and I can scan any QR code, but the color that shows the camera is not the correct...

For example, the screen of the computer is blue (and sometimes orange) with the camera.

I'm using the Zxing library with this apk:

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/releases/tag/BSGlass-0.2.1

Any suggestion?

PD: I've tried to edit the file: CameraConfigurationManager.java with the instructions:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
parameters.setPreviewSize(640,360);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

But it not works well yet.

Thanks so much.